# Control exact position of page number

Tags: positioning, page-numbering

I have page number for some first few pages in roman style (`\pagenumbering{roman}`) and the rest arabic (`\pagenumber{arabic}`).

Now it need to position them such that:

- page number should be 3/4 of an inch from the bottom edge of the page.
- they should be flush with the right page margin.

I've tried

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\rfoot{\thepage}
```

but page numbers position in the middle of bottom page. 
Also, I don't know how to change the position of page number with respect to bottom of the page.

Can someone please help?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{report}
\usepackage[
  top    = 1in,
  bottom = 0.75in,
  left   = 1.25in,
  right  = 1.25in,
  headsep=5mm,%%% Example
  includeheadfoot,%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% clearsall
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\normalsize foo}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to add a \thispagestyle{fancy} to the first page of each chapter, or redefine pagestyle plain to be fancy.  (\let\ps@plain=\ps@fancy)

Comment: no, I do not need that. I always use plain on chapter pages.

Comment: hmm, I got some page numbers flushed to the right correctly, but then some pages have the page numbers in the middle. really weird. Can't find what causes this.

Comment: btw, here's the variation I used.

Comment: that are the pages where a chapter starts. You have to define `\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}\rfoot{\thepage}}`

Comment: ah, righ. that was the variation I used too: https://github.com/khanh-nguyen/dummy-text/blob/master/0-main.tex#L96

Comment: why the style is fine, I'm still getting the page number located 2inches from the bottom edge of the page instead of 1inch. This is [my settings](https://gist.github.com/khanh-nguyen/5e0fdb34ec6f2e295d90#file-preamble-tex-L7). Do you know the reason why, @Herbert?

Comment: Delete the lines `\textheight=..` and `\textwidth=..` That should all  be done by the settings of `geometry`